# TypeScript exporting interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing typings for a library and I wonder how can I export an interface so it can be imported and used this way:

```
import * as S from './sanctuary/index';

const myS: Sanctuary = S.create(); // create new instance with different settings
myS.add(1, 2);

S.add(1, 2); // also be able to use the default instance
```

Minimal example:

```
// Should be somehow reachable
interface Maybe<A>{
  of: <B>(value: B) => Maybe<B>;
}

// Should be able to import as *
interface Sanctuary {

//# create :: { checkTypes :: Boolean, env :: Array Type } -> Module
  create(properties: {checkTypes: boolean, env: SanctuaryType[]}): Sanctuary;

  add(first: number, second: number): number;
}
```

Notice the return type of `create`. At first I was writing it with namespaces but I couldn't figure out how to return the "type" of namespace.

```
export as namespace S;

export function create(properties: {checkTypes: boolean,
  env: SanctuaryType[]}): S; // <- does not compile
```

How to modify/rewrite it so it can be imported as shown at the beginning?

---

Edit1: I also need to export other interfaces. (edited example)

I had some success with `export = <Santcuary>{};` and then `import S = require('./sanctuary/index');` (which is not ideal, but I suppose usable). But I have no idea how to export all other interfaces, because when using `export =` TS won't allow it. Is it even possible to do it?

Comment: you can use `declare namespace S;`

Comment: @Jigar could you be more specific? I tried `export declare namespace S {
  export function create(): S;
}` but it fails to compile with `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'S'.`.

Comment: Within the export function you just write `export declare namespace S { export function create(): Sanctuary; }`

Comment: But then I won't have exported all functions that are on Sanctuary, will I?. All add another example of how it is supposed to be consumed.